# Error on importing pyvttbl

Tags: python

I installed pyvttbl using pip, but now python can't import pyvttbl lib as it gives me the error shown in the image below. It says that there's no module named as "base".

[image]

Is there anything wrong?!

I'm running on python 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this python module you are trying to use it not compatible with python 3.6.1. i try to figure out what was going on and it wouldn't run for me i made sure everything was up to date then realized this module was last updated in 2013. and is not compatible with 3.6. how ever i did get it to work in python 2.7.8

hope this helped.